# Deploying maven artifacts for different JVM versions

Tags: maven, versioning

For the release of Jaybird (Firebird JDBC driver) we also want to release to the Maven repository. I am now considering how to name/version the artifacts, as there is a different version for each supported Java version (for the upcoming Jaybird 2.2 it would be a version for Java 5/JDBC 3, Java 6/JDBC 4.0 and Java 7/JDBC 4.1).

I have found three different ways of naming JVM specific versions:

1. JVM version in the artifact (eg `<artifactId>jaybird-jdk15</<artifactId>`)
2. JVM version in the version (eg `<version>2.2.0-jdk15</version>`)
3. Using the classifier (eg `<classifier>jdk15</classifier>`)

As the builds have different sourcecode one could consider the JVM variants to be actually different artifacts (option 1). I have seen that PostgreSQL JDBC uses option 2. Option 3 has (AFAIK) the downside that you can't include version specific sources and javadoc.

I would like to know if I have missed a totally different option or maven-feature for JVM specific artifacts, or if there is a preferred method for versioning these types of artifacts.

NOTE: The Jaybird build process itself does **not** use Maven

Comment: Just another datapoint, oracle uses option 1 with their artifacts named ojdbc14, ojdbc5 or ojdbc6. I think the classifier would be the right approach, but you raise a very good point about attached source and javadoc artifacts.

Comment: [testng](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/testng/testng/5.10/) used `Option 3` prior to version `5.11` for `jdk14` and `jdk15`. It also deployed `source` and `javadoc` but not sure if they were common for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the fact that the source code is different for both, I'd go w/ option 1.  It really is a different artifact.

Now, if you combined all the source into one tree, and used profiles to build the different artifacts, I'd go w/ option 3.  But only if it became more of one source code base.

Comment: The build itself does not use Maven, and the way the differences between the JVM versions are coded and structured it is not easy to get a single codebase.

Comment: How you build and generate the artifacts (using maven or not) isn't really important.  It's the availability of those artifacts to other projects using maven that makes the differences important.